# ReferenceError: tdbMenu is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: pagespeed, referenceerror

how are you? I need help resolving this issue on my website. I tested using Pagespeed Insight and this same error is occurring on all pages. Please I would like help to resolve this. I'm using the newspaper template as a base.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

This problem is causing my website's performance to decrease.